# How to share assets between Android and Java?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Gradle build, that is producing Android and Java library artifacts. But both should include the same assets. Here is what I want to have:

Project A: Contains assets used by B and C(mostly text files)
Project B: Is a standard java-library project depending on A.
Project C: Is a standard android-library project depending on A.

After some research I have identified the following possible solutions:

1. Manually copy the contents from A to B and C.
2. Set A as source folder in B and C: srcDirs("../A/src/main/assets")
3. Make A produce variants, that can be correctly consumed by B and C.

I don't like 1. for obvious reasons. 2. is discouraged by Gradle, because it breaks Gradle features like build cache or configuration cache. Which leaves me with 3.

Making A produce a variant, that can be consumed by B is easier. But producing a variant, that can be consumed by an Android Gradle plugin project seems really tricky. And it does not help, that the Android Gradle plugin is closed source.

This is what I have tried so far:
A/build.gradle.kts

```
val assets by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = false
    attributes {
        attribute(io.payworks.artifactTypeAttribute, "android-assets")
    }
    outgoing {
        artifact(file("src/main/assets"))
    }
}
```

C/build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies{
    implementation(project(":A"))
}
```

But it fails with this message:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of null.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':C:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > No variants of project :A match the consumer attributes:
       - Configuration ':A:assets':
           - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-assets' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'artifactType' with value 'android-classes-jar'
           - Other compatible attributes:
               - Doesn't say anything about asm-transformed-variant (required 'NONE')
               - Doesn't say anything about com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr (required 'debug')
               - Doesn't say anything about dexing-enable-desugaring (required 'true')
               - Doesn't say anything about dexing-is-debuggable (required 'true')
               - Doesn't say anything about dexing-min-sdk (required '21')
               - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
               - Doesn't say anything about its usage (required a runtime)
               - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
```